# Past Perfect Tense in Reported Speech

Tags: past-perfect, reported-speech

> Police had deployed large forces along the major junctions of Hosur Road, where major protests took place on Monday.

<sup>([Source: Times of India](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/bengaluru/Violent-protests-in-Bengaluru-against-PF-withdrawal-norms-several-vehicles-torched/articleshow/51893679.cms))</sup>

In above sentence which I read in new paper past perfect tense has been used. Past perfect tense is used to refer past of past. I am unable to make out two pasts in above sentence.

Does it mean Police were already aware of this protest on Sunday or before protest and already deployed last forces along the major junctions on Sunday or before protest? I mean deployment of forces is first past and taking place of protest is second past.

Comment: Lots of text in *The Times of India* isn't exactly "standard English". The article you're citing repeatedly switches between ***police*** and ***cops***, for example, which is somewhat bizarre. And the paragraph immediately following your cite contains *Later mobs **started** gathering near Hebbagodi, located around 20km from city. Once police **started** chasing them out, the mob **started** setting vehicles on fire*, which sounds unbelievably clunky to me. Past perfect is "acceptable" in this case - but totally unnecessary, and conveys no information that's not contextually implicit anyway.

Comment: **had deployed...took place**  Police had stationed themselves in anticipation of protests which later took place..

Comment: When you use past perfect, the two different past times ***don't have to be*** in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the whole article, the timeline is like this:

- Monday: Demonstrations in Hosur road
- Early Tuesday: police deployed forces in Hosur Road
- 9:30 Tuesday: demonstrators started throwing stones at police
- Later: police started caning demonstrators
- Later still: demonstrators set fire to cars
- Even later: police fired over the heads of demonstrators
- 1pm: the situation was under control again.

The headline report is about the violence (caning, arson, gunfire) sometime after 9:30 on Tuesday: this is therefore the main timeline event. The police had **already** deployed (Tuesday morning, before 9:30). This is before the main timeline event, hence the use of past perfect.